# Add/edit string in compiled C program?

Tags: c++, c, ansi-c, hex-editors

I have a strange question, I am wondering if there is a way to add/edit a string (or something that could be accessed via the C program (inside, ie not an external file)) after it has been compiled?

The purpose is to change a URL on an Windows program via PHP on Linux (obviously I cannot just compile it).

Comment: Probably but do you really wanna do that

Comment: Your OS might have a checksum attached to the executable (Windows PE, for example, has one). Come think of it: there is actually a way -- if your OS doesn't mind! (1) Compile your program with a dummy placeholder value. (2) Note the size. (3) Place size in placeholder value. (4) Recompile. If you get the same size, you can use the value to access data that you paste (physically!) at the 'end' of the executable.

Comment: You're probably going to run into a lot of issues if you end up changing the length of the string.

Comment: To add to Jongware's comment, on iOS (and sometimes OS X) you'd need to re-sign the binary afterward.

Comment: You've left the question fairly vague and nebulous. You could be a new programmer looking to discover IO or string concatenation, or a script-kiddy trying to figure out if he can change a 'login:' prompt to 'penis:', or you could be a seasoned engineer trying to devise an extreme anti-hack mechanism whereby you don't put the strings into a run-time until it's loaded.

Comment: "Edit" is clear (given the overall vagueness), but what would "adding"  a string mean? For fairly obvious reasons, you cannot willy-nilly *add* a new string to an executable and believe it will "do" something, when it doesn't *expect* a variable number of strings.

Comment: I did leave the question a little vague you are right, but I got the answers I needed. The purpose is to change a URL on an Windows program via PHP on Linux (obviously I cannot just compile it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many posix platforms come with the program `strings` which will read through a binary file searching for strings.  There is an option to print out the offset of the strings.  For example:

```
strings -td myexec
```

From there you can use a hex editor but the main problem is that you wouldn't be able to make a string *bigger* than it already is.

Comment: A common workaround for longer strings is to reserve lots of extra space. But since the OP is unclear on whether s/he wrote the original executable, this may not be an option.

Comment: How do you make a string smaller?

Comment: It actually depends on the string.  If you are lucky it is null terminated and you can just null off your shorter string.  If it is a string with length byte stored somewhere then obviously you have to find and alter that.

Answer (score 1):

A Hex Editor is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

A hex editor will work, but you have to be careful not to alter the size of the executable. If the string happens to be in the .res file, you can use ResEdit.

Answer (score 1):

There are specialized tools to modify existing executable files. A notable tool is 
[Resource Tuner](http://www.restuner.com/tour-resourceeditor.htm), which can be used to edit all sorts of resources in an executable.

Another option is to use a text editor, like [Hex Workshop](http://www.hexworkshop.com/), to edit the characters in the strings of an executable. However, bear in mind that with this method, you can only edit existing strings in an executable, and the replaced strings must have an equal or smaller length than the original ones, otherwise you'll end up modifying executable code.

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, you can use a binary file editor (hex editor) to change the string in the executable file.  You will want to embed into the string a marker (unique sequence of bytes) so that you can find the string in your file.  And you will want to ensure that you are reading/writing the file at correct offsets.

As OP stated plans to use PHP on linux to rewrite the file, you will need to use fseek to position the file pointer to the starting location of this URL string, ensure you stay within the size of the string as you replace bytes, and then use fseek/rewind and fwrite to change the file.

This technique can be used to change a URL embedded in a binary file, and it can also be used to embed a license key into a binary, or to embed an application checksum value into a binary so that one can detect when the binary has changed.

As some posters have suggested, you may need to recompute a checksum or re-sign a binary file.  A quick way to check for this behavior would be to compile two versions of your binary with different URL values.  Then compare the files and see if there are differences other than in the URL values.

Answer (score 1):

to properly edit a string in a compiled program you need to:

1. read in the files bytes
2. search the .rdata for strings and record the address of the first occurrence of the string
3. convert that address to the virtual address using some of the data in the file header
4. write a new .rdata onto the executable and write your new string into it recording its address and getting its virtual address.
5. search the .text section for references to the virtual address of the old string and replace it with the reference to your new string.

fortunately i made a program to do this on windows it only works on 32 bit programs [here](http://botliam.xyz/StringEditor.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you want to poke around in the generated hex or assembly code.